MS Word didn't saved correctly
It appeared that word hasn't saved correctly.
The situation was as followed: the document was opened for a longer period of time (I am aware that this is not the way to go, but it is what it is). While working on the paper, the document was saved multiple times without a complaint. It was saved at least once a day, which should lead to at least 7 entries in history. After that period, the document was saved in a different location as a backup copy and also copied by hand and sent per email. But it looks like that by the time the document was closed, all the work that was done since the last time opening was deleted. While closing the document, words wasn't complaining about unsaved changes.
That being sag: those changes are lost. Not shown in the history at all. In none of the copies is anything of the change.
I looked through some of the unsaved app-data traces from Microsoft, checked the file in OneDrive.
I also looked at the documents that have been opened recently to check whether the file was saved at another location.
Therefore, I looked under "Documents" whether word has saved it there and also used the Microsoft document search on C to see equivalent documents.
Now I am curious whether there is a word-expert around, which is having an idea what else can be done to restore the data.
I would love to have some inspiration what to try, hoping to recover the data.
Software used: word and onedrive 365

look in the sent folder of the email client

Of course I did. But in the sent document weren't any changes
